# onsubmit() form on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, forms, mobile, browser, onsubmit

I current use a javascript function on the onsubmit() event of my form to check if all the input are not empty.

This works fine on computer, but on mobile phone, it changes the background color (as I want to do when the input is empty) but it still submits the form !!!

My form :

```
<form id="formContact" action="envoi-message.php" method="post" class="normal" onsubmit="return valideChamps();">
            <div class="ddl">
                <span>VOUS ÊTES...</span>
                <div class="ddlOption">
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="ddlContact('entreprise')"><span>UNE ENTREPRISE</span></li>
                        <li onclick="ddlContact('ecole')"><span>UNE &Eacute;COLE</span></li>
                        <li onclick="ddlContact('personne')"><span>UNE PERSONNE</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="cache" type="text" name="entreprise" placeholder="NOM DE L'ENTREPRISE" />
            <input class="cache" type="text" name="ecole" placeholder="NOM DE L'&Eacute;COLE" />
            <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="VOTRE NOM" />
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="VOTRE EMAIL" />
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="VOTRE MESSAGE" ></textarea>
            <input id="btnEnvoi" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
        </form>
```

My function :

```
    function valideChamps(){
    var bResult = true;
    if ($("input[name*='nom']").val() == "") {
        $("input[name*='nom']").addClass("error");
        bResult = false;
    } else {
        $("input[name*='nom']").removeClass("error");
    }
    if ($("input[name*='email']").val() == "") {
        $("input[name*='email']").addClass("error");
        bResult = false;
    } else {
        var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if (regex.test($("input[name*='email']").val()) == false ) {
            $("input[name*='email']").addClass("error");
            bResult = false;
        } else {
            $("input[name*='email']").removeClass("error");
        }
    }                                      
    if ($("#formContact textarea").val() == ""){
        $("#formContact textarea").addClass("error");
        bResult = false;
    }else {
        $("#formContact textarea").removeClass("error");
    }
    if ($("div.ddl > span").text().contains("entreprise")){
        if ($("input[name*='entreprise']").val() == "") {
            $("input[name*='entreprise']").addClass("error");
            bResult = false;
        }else {
            $("input[name*='entreprise']").removeClass("error");
        }
    } else if ($("div.ddl > span").text().contains("école")){
        if ($("input[name*='ecole']").val() == "") {
            $("input[name*='ecole']").addClass("error");
            bResult = false;
        }else {
            $("input[name*='ecole']").removeClass("error");
        }
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

Do you have any idea about what is wrong...?
Best regards
Audrey

EDIT : I changed my submit button; I put a  with onclick which submits the form if bResut == true

Comment: Define "mobile phone". Which browsers have you tested? Do they all show that behaviour? Have you checked that `bResult` holds the value that you expect?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your submit handler to the form using JS, so you can access the event and call preventDefault() instead of (or in addition to) returning false;
Like so:

```
document.getElementById('formContact').onsubmit = function(e) {
  //your validateChamps stuff goes here
if(!bResult) e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but even if it works on computer, it's always the same problem on mobile... :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I changed my submit button; I put a with onclick which submits the form if bResut == true